# How to replace useEffect hook with component lifecycle?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm forced to use class based component, so how can I replace `useEffect` with   component lifecycle like componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount in my React component.
Please help

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
```

Comment: For that specific `useEffect` call, use `componentDidMount`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you forced to use a class based component?

Answer (score 2):

As React team mentioned in this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

So if you want to use life cycles you have to use `class`
.

Use class that extends `Component`  and it must be like this :

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  //you can use components lifecycle here for example : 

  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After delcaring the constructor you should put the componentDidMount method just ahead, like this:

```
class yourComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      // constructor taks...
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      // what you want to do when the component mount
   }
}
```